# <a class="link" href="javascript:;">edit</a>

Tags: javascript

I am seeing this code in a PHP smarty template file *.tpl:

```
<span id="crmspanid" style="display:none;position:absolute;"  onmouseover="show('crmspanid');">
    <a class="link"  href="javascript:;">{$APP.EDIT_BUTTON}</a>
</span>
```

$APP.EDIT_BUTTON is essentially an english workd Edit, hence the above line translates to:

```
<a class="link" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
```

I'd think `<a class="link" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>` makes "Edit" appear as a link but does nothing when clicking on it.

The show function is like this:

```
function show(divId)

{
    if(getObj(divId))
    {
        var id = document.getElementById(divId);

        id.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

However in this page, if Edit is clicked, the page gets 'expanded' a bit, and a text box together with a couple of buttons are shown:[image] (this is the text box and a Save button and Cancel link that appear after clicking on the Edit).

I am lost as to how to find where the code is which gets gone through after Edit is clicked. Any thoughts are welcomed! many thanks.

Comment: The event may be added dynamically with `addEventListener` or with equivalent method

Answer (score 1):

Someone attached an `onclick` handler to the link which contains the actual code that is executed. The `href` attribute seems to be just a dummy.

Answer (score 1):

The click event handler is probably added with JavaScript code that runs on page load.  Look through your JavaScript for the code that runs on page load, then you should be able to find the code that adds the click event handler.

It's not good practice to add event handlers in the HTML.  This is something you should be doing in JavaScript.  It's also bad practice to use `href="javascript:"` - links should have real destinations for reliability and accessibility reasons.